# What remote does "git push" push to when there is no origin?

Tags: git

Is there a command to check what remote `git push` and `git pull` will use?

All the documentation I have found states that `git push` will push to the origin if a remote is not specified, however nothing is mentioned about what happens when there is no origin. I also know that the default remote can be changed.

My Git repository does not have a `origin` remote and when I try `git push` it I get the error below.

```
fatal: No destination configured to push to.
```

I have tried `git remote -v` but that just lists all my remotes and their urls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each branch in your local repository can have a remote (it doesn't have to be called `origin`) set as its "upstream". This is where gets pushed to.

You can issue `git push -u <remote> <branch>` to push and define the upstream for future pushes and pulls.

If you cat the `.git/config` file in your local repository, you can see all the branches for which an upstream is defined. It looks like this:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

The merge field defines the remote head that's associated with your local one. The remote and local branch don't have to have the same name, but for the sake of clarity it is better if they do.

**edited:** there was a very unfortunate typo in there: I had written "push -i" instead of "push -u"